# アコーディオン表示のテーブルのフィルターがうまく動作しない

Tags: javascript, html, css

#### 実現したいこと

アコーディオン表示のテーブルに下記の動きをするフィルターを追加したい

- 小カテゴリのA,B,C,Dのセレクトボックスで任意の名前を選択すると、
  名前が同じ行と選択した名前を含む中カテゴリのチーム名と大カテゴリのグループ名を表示

例：　Cを選択した場合
　　
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 困っていること

- フィルターでB,C,Dを選択したときに不正表示になってしまう
- フィルターの動作箇所の`while (nextRow && !nextRow.querySelector(".accordion-button")) {`と`if (nextRow.matches(".accordion-content")) {`が不正という認識ですが、どのようにすれば考えている表示ができるのかわからない状態

#### 試したこと

- コメントアウトの`フィルターの動作`部分を作成

※データについては固定
どのように改善していいか検討もつかず困っています... どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

```js
data = [{
    "name": "グループ1",
    "time": "i分s秒",
    "child": [{
        "name": "チーム1",
        "time": "i分s秒",
        "grand": [{
            "name": "A",
            "time": "i分s秒"
          },
          {
            "name": "B",
            "time": "i分s秒"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "チーム2",
        "time": "i分s秒",
        "grand": [{
            "name": "C",
            "time": "i分s秒"
          },
          {
            "name": "D",
            "time": "i分s秒"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "グループ2",
    "time": "i分s秒",
    "child": [{
        "name": "チーム3",
        "time": "i分s秒",
        "grand": [{
            "name": "A",
            "time": "i分s秒"
          },
          {
            "name": "C",
            "time": "i分s秒"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "チーム4",
        "time": "i分s秒",
        "grand": [{
            "name": "B",
            "time": "i分s秒"
          },
          {
            "name": "D",
            "time": "i分s秒"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const tableBody = document.querySelector("table tbody");
// テーブル作成
data.forEach((item) => {
  const row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.innerHTML = `<td class="accordion-button">${item.name}</td>
                   <td>${item.time}</td>`;
  tableBody.appendChild(row);
  if (item.child) {
    item.child.forEach((classInfo) => {
      const classRow = document.createElement("tr");
      classRow.innerHTML = `<td class="accordion-child-button">${classInfo.name}</td>
                            <td>${classInfo.time}</td>`;
      tableBody.appendChild(classRow);
      classRow.classList.add('accordion-content');
      if (classInfo.grand) {
        classInfo.grand.forEach((grandInfo) => {
          const grandRow = document.createElement("tr");
          grandRow.innerHTML = `<td>${grandInfo.name}</td>
                                <td>${grandInfo.time}</td>`;
          tableBody.appendChild(grandRow);
          grandRow.classList.add('accordion-content1');
        });
      }
    });
  }
});


const accordionButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-button");
const accordionChildButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-child-button");

// アコーディオン表示（大カテゴリ押下時）
accordionButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let childRow = button.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    while (childRow && !childRow.querySelector(".accordion-button")) {
      if (childRow.matches(".show, .accordion-content"))
        childRow.classList.toggle("show");
      childRow = childRow.nextElementSibling;
    }
  });
});
// 大カテゴリ押下時（中カテゴリ押下時）
accordionChildButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let childRow = button.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    while (childRow && childRow.matches(".accordion-content1")) {
      childRow.classList.toggle("show");
      childRow = childRow.nextElementSibling;
    }
  });
});

// フィルター部分のオプション切り出し
const selectElement = document.getElementById("category");
const grandNames = new Set();
data.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.child) {
    item.child.forEach((classInfo) => {
      if (classInfo.grand) {
        classInfo.grand.forEach((grandInfo) => {
          grandNames.add(grandInfo.name);
        });
      }
    });
  }
});

// フィルター部分に表示内容を追加
grandNames.forEach((grandName) => {
  const option = document.createElement("option");
  option.textContent = grandName;
  option.value = grandName;
  selectElement.appendChild(option);
});

const accordionContent1 = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-content1");
// フィルターの動作
selectElement.addEventListener("change", () => {
  const selectedGrandName = selectElement.value;
  accordionContent1.forEach((row) => {
    const nameColumn = row.querySelector("td:first-child");
    if (selectedGrandName === nameColumn.textContent) {
      row.classList.toggle("show");
      let nextRow = row.previousElementSibling;
      while (nextRow && !nextRow.querySelector(".accordion-button")) {
        if (nextRow.matches(".accordion-content")) {
          nextRow.classList.toggle("show");
        }
        nextRow = nextRow.previousElementSibling;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
<style>
/* テーブルのスタイル */

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}


/* アコーディオンボタンのスタイル */

.accordion-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.accordion-child-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #B0E0E6;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.accordion-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 8px;
}

.accordion-content1 {
  display: none;
  padding: 8px;
}

.show {
  display: table-row;
}

</style>
```

```html
<label>フィルター</label>
<select id="category">
  <option category_id=""></option>
</select>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一旦自己解決した為記載します。

> - フィルターでB,C,Dを選択したときに不正表示になってしまう
> - フィルターの動作箇所のwhile (nextRow && !nextRow.querySelector(".accordion-button")) {とif
>   (nextRow.matches(".accordion-content"))
>   {が不正という認識ですが、どのようにすれば考えている表示ができるのかわからない状態

不正表示になるのは、`if (nextRow.matches(".accordion-content")) {`に複数回入っていることが原因でした。その為、`break;`を追加することで改善しました。

```js
data = [{
  "name": "グループ1",
  "time": "i分s秒",
  "child": [{
      "name": "チーム1",
      "time": "i分s秒",
      "grand": [{
          "name": "A",
          "time": "i分s秒"
        },
        {
          "name": "B",
          "time": "i分s秒"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "チーム2",
      "time": "i分s秒",
      "grand": [{
          "name": "C",
          "time": "i分s秒"
        },
        {
          "name": "D",
          "time": "i分s秒"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "グループ2",
  "time": "i分s秒",
  "child": [
    {
      "name": "チーム3",
      "time": "i分s秒",
      "grand": [
        {
          "name": "A",
          "time": "i分s秒"
        },
        {
          "name": "C",
          "time": "i分s秒"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "チーム4",
      "time": "i分s秒",
      "grand": [
        {
          "name": "B",
          "time": "i分s秒"
        },
        {
          "name": "D",
          "time": "i分s秒"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];

const tableBody = document.querySelector("table tbody");
// テーブル作成
data.forEach((item) => {
  const row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.innerHTML = `<td class="accordion-button">${item.name}</td>
                   <td>${item.time}</td>`;
  tableBody.appendChild(row);
  if (item.child) {
    item.child.forEach((classInfo) => {
      const classRow = document.createElement("tr");
      classRow.innerHTML = `<td class="accordion-child-button">${classInfo.name}</td>
                            <td>${classInfo.time}</td>`;
      tableBody.appendChild(classRow);
      classRow.classList.add('accordion-content');
      if (classInfo.grand) {
        classInfo.grand.forEach((grandInfo) => {
          const grandRow = document.createElement("tr");
          grandRow.innerHTML = `<td>${grandInfo.name}</td>
                                <td>${grandInfo.time}</td>`;
          tableBody.appendChild(grandRow);
          grandRow.classList.add('accordion-content1');
        });
      }
    });
  }
});

// フィルター部分のオプション切り出し
const selectElement = document.getElementById("category");
const grandNames = new Set();
data.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.child) {
    item.child.forEach((classInfo) => {
      if (classInfo.grand) {
        classInfo.grand.forEach((grandInfo) => {
          grandNames.add(grandInfo.name);
        });
      }
    });
  }
});

// フィルター部分に表示内容を追加
grandNames.forEach((grandName) => {
  const option = document.createElement("option");
  option.textContent = grandName;
  option.value = grandName;
  selectElement.appendChild(option);
});

const accordionButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-button");
const accordionChildButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-child-button");
const accordionContent1 = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-content1");
const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr");
let selectedGrandName;

// 大カテゴリ押下時
accordionButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(selectedGrandName){
      selectElement.options[0].selected = true;
      selectedGrandName = selectElement.value;
      removeShow();
    } else {
      let childRow = button.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
      while (childRow && !childRow.querySelector(".accordion-button")) {
        if (childRow.matches(".show, .accordion-content")){
          childRow.classList.toggle("show");
        }
        childRow = childRow.nextElementSibling;
      }
    }
  });
});

// 中カテゴリ押下時
accordionChildButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(selectedGrandName){
      console.log(selectedGrandName);
      selectElement.options[0].selected = true;
      selectedGrandName = selectElement.value;
      removeShow();
    } else {
      let childRow = button.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
      while (childRow && childRow.matches(".accordion-content1")) {
        childRow.classList.toggle("show");
        childRow = childRow.nextElementSibling;
      }
    }
  });
});

// フィルターの動作
selectElement.addEventListener("change", () => {
  selectedGrandName = selectElement.value;
  // テーブル初期化
  removeShow();
  // 表示対象が選択されている場合
  if (selectedGrandName) {
    accordionContent1.forEach((row) => {
      const nameColumn = row.querySelector("td:first-child");
      if (selectedGrandName === nameColumn.textContent) {
        toggleAccordionRows(row);
      }
    });
  }
});

// テーブル表示初期化
function removeShow() {
  tableRows.forEach((row) => {
    row.classList.remove("show");
  });
}

// アコーディオン行のトグル
function toggleAccordionRows(row) {
  row.classList.toggle("show");
  let nextRow = row.previousElementSibling;
  while (nextRow && !nextRow.querySelector(".accordion-button")) {
    if (nextRow.matches(".accordion-content")) {
      nextRow.classList.toggle("show");
      break;
    }
    nextRow = nextRow.previousElementSibling;
  }
}
```

```css
<style>
/* テーブルのスタイル */

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}


/* アコーディオンボタンのスタイル */

.accordion-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.accordion-child-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #B0E0E6;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.accordion-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 8px;
}

.accordion-content1 {
  display: none;
  padding: 8px;
}

.show {
  display: table-row;
}
</style>
```

```html
<label>フィルター</label>
<select id="category">
  <option category_id=""></option>
</select>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```